# Java AES key generation

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm trying to write a simple password manager in java. I would like to encrypt the file with the stored passwords using AES 256 bit encryption. In addition I would like the user to be able to decrypt the file with a password. When reading other posts online almost all of them stress that it is not secure to simply use a password as a key, they mention using random salts to add security. But I do not understand how I can use random salts when generating the key. If I create the key from the user's password and a random salt then when they try to decrypt their file how will I know what the salt was? This has me completely confused.

Currently I run their password through several different hashes using a constant salt at each step. Is this sufficiently secure or I am I missing something? Any help on how to securely generate a key from a password would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to add an HMAC of the encrypted data to the end of the file to provide some tamper protection. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that **a salt isn't a secret**. You can just append it to the encrypted data. The point of the salt is to prevent somebody from using a pre-computed dictionary of common pieces of data encrypted with common passwords as a way into "cracking" the encrypted file.

By making sure that the salt is **random** and combining it with the password, you remove the possibility of a dictionary attack because there's (effectively) no chance that a hacker will have a database of data pre-encrypted with your "salt+password". (As a starter, see this page, from one of my tutorials, on [salts in password-based encryption](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/pbe_salt.shtml).)

You also (effectively) eliminate the problem of **collisions**: where using the same password on two files may give an attacker a clue to the content if the same block of data occurring in both files looks the same in the encrypted version.

You still usually need to take other precautions, though, simply because a typical password doesn't usually contain much *entropy*. For example, 8 perfectly random lower case letters will generate about 40 bits of entropy; 8 lower case letters obeying typical patterns of English will generate about 20 bits of entropy. In other words, of the 2^256 possible keys, in reality typical users will be choosing among some small fraction in the range 2^20-2^40. In the case of a savvy user, the situation gets a little better, but you will be very unlikely to get close to 256 bits of entropy. (Consider that in a "pass phrase", there'll be about 2.5-3 bits of entropy per character, so a 30-character pass phrase gives you about 75 bits of entropy-- and let's be honest, how many people use anything like a 30 character password?; 8 perfectly random characters using the 'full' range of printable ASCII will give you a little under 64 bits.)

One way of alleviating this situation a little is to **transform the password** (with salt appended) **using a computationally complex one-way function** so that it will take a hacker a little longer to try each key that they want to guess. Again, [see this page for more details](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/pbe_key_derivation.shtml).

To give you a rough idea of the pitfalls of password-based encryption of files, you may also want to have a look at the [Arcmexer library](http://www.javamex.com/arcmexer/) I wrote a couple of years ago, which includes a method named isProbablyCorrectPassword(). Combined with a dictionary/algorithm for generating candidate passwords, you can use it to gauge the effectiveness of the above methods (since ZIP file encryption uses a combination of these techniques).

Comment: Thanks! That makes much more sense, you're tutorial was great as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use this library: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

There's a good AES example ere:

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/AES.java.html

A lot of big names use this package, Maven, Eclipse, etc.

Comment: This seems overly complex for encrypting a file using AES256. Most of the code in the example is for handling a SSH2 connection.